# ViewState error on shared web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am working on a web store app using C#  3.5 web forms and MS SQL Server 2008. The solution runs fine on VS2010, using the built-in web server. Then I upload the project to a testing sub-domain and the home page loads; as soon as I click on a menu link, I get this: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. This didn't occur early in my project and I haven't built anything weird or bizarre, normal CRUD stuff with a session-variable menu structure concept. I am stumped and now I seek help from the stackoverflow genius pool. Any suggestions?

I am pasting the stack trace info from the error page:

```
[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: omitted by user
Port: 53604
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)
ViewState: /wEPDwULLTEwMDUyNjYzMjhkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYMBRJjdGwwMCRpbWdCX05hcGtpbnMFFmN0bDAwJGltZ0JfVGFibGVjbG90aHMFEmN0bDAwJGltZ0JfUnVubmVycwUSY3RsMDAkaW1nQl9QaWxsb3dzBRFjdGwwMCRpbWdCX0Fwcm9ucwUQY3RsMDAkaW1nQl9XcmFwcwURY3RsMDAkaW1nQl9RdWlsdHMFEmN0bDAwJGltZ0JfSG9saWRheQUUY3RsMDAkaW1nQl9PdXRlcndlYXIFEmN0bDAwJGltZ0JfSnVkYWljYQUTY3RsMDAkaW1nQl9LaWRTdHVmZgUVY3RsMDAkaW1nQl9CYXJnYWluQmlufgoWd3FjkchVtkJTfTl/dw7C/Ks=
Referer: http://omitted by user/
Path: /Default.aspx]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.]
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +106
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +237
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +207
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +105
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6785
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +242
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2e1de3e2\ec16856d\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.2xg-fqvv.0.cs:0
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

hope this helps. I am trying to get the attention of my web hosting company, but they are not answering my ticket. I really want to call them out, but I'll restrain for now.

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was created by the webhosting company upgrading to AspNet 4.0 and my local dev project is targeting 3.5 sp1. I solved the viewstate issue by matching the target framework and it works great now. Just a suggestion to check the version as part of any trouble-shooting efforts.

thanks for the help, stackoverflow genius pool.

Comment: Is it ok to answer your own question? I just lost 2 points, oh well. Like I have a thousand to give up. Ha. This site is very helpful every time I get stumped.

Answer (score 1):

> I am stumped and now I seek help from the stackoverflow genius pool. Any suggestions?

I suggest to set the machineKey on web.config, for example:

```
<machineKey 
validationKey="NXBXUKMF19UN5SCJX1SF5XXTR0MK4EYAMBJ 5GYRPAGMBAAGGADANBGKQHKIG9W0B" 
decryptionKey="RNNWWNSU7WJBAMQ8R4XAOMIH7SPRZPF7LHI MRHWVIF2AB7NA6AII7OXYE2JSX7ZM"
validation="SHA1"    
/>
```

Comment: Additional reference can be found here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations.  Here's an online tool you can use to generate a machinekey. http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added the enableMACviewstate="false" attribute to the pages element in the web.config file. This corrected the problem. There seems to be an internal AspNet bug that adds to this problem. I don't know if the webhost server is clustered or not, but the problem is gone and I hope I haven't opened up any security issue with this change. Thanks again, Robert.

Comment: @rjsteward This is not correct the problem :) just stops the validation. Yes you open a security issue, now I do not know what you post, maybe is not so critical and they are simple pages (with out database and critical data), if not, try to correct the problem and validate again the viewstate.

Comment: thank you, always learning.... the session variables were broken by doing this. I turned the viewstateMAC to true and will learn how to vaildate the viewstate object.

Comment: This is what we had to do at work. Our admins setup a bad web cluster with mismatching machineKeys. This is the only fix as far as I know.